# using odbc to connect to open office

Tags: c#, odbc, openoffice.org

wanted to know if there is a way to connect to open office calc (Same as MS Excel) using odbc and run sql commands.  I am able to do this using Excel and odbc in C#.  Can this be done in C# using odbc and open office calc.

Comment: I don't know the connection string that is my issue

Comment: wait i will give u...try that one

Comment: wait...i am trying out different combinations...lets see what happens...but really good question...

Comment: can I ask why this was closed.  How will it "likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion"  its very simple I asked how it can be done and if someone did it tell me how

Answer (score 0):

```
provider=Microsoft.ACE.oledb.12.0;datasource=path of db
```

try to have this connection string